# Why does the curve not show?

Tags: manipulate

I am trying to plot a general helix with variable parameters (via sliders) and its associated FrenetSerretSystem. The helix doesn't show.

```
helix = {a*Cos[(\[Omega]*s)/c], a*Sin[(\[Omega]*s)/c], (b*s)/c};
basis = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[helix, s]] // Simplify;
{tangent, normal, binormal} = 
  Map[Arrow[{helix, helix + #}] &, basis];
tangent
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[helix, {s, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black},
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",] // Evaluate, 
   Graphics3D[{Thick, Blue, Dynamic[tangent], Red, Dynamic[normal], 
     Purple, Dynamic[binormal]}],
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
   Boxed -> False,
   PlotRange -> All] // Evaluate, {{s, 5}, 0, 10}, {{a, 1}, 0, 
  10}, {{b, 1}, 0, 10}, {{c, 1}, 0, 10}, {{\[Omega], 5}, 0, 10},
 ContinuousAction -> True,
 SaveDefinitions -> True,
 Initialization :> ({a = 2, b = 1, c = 1, \[Omega] = 5})
 ]
```

If I fix the parameters it is working:

```
With[{a = 2, b = 1, 
       c = 1, \[Omega] = 5}, \[Beta][s_] = {a*Cos[(\[Omega]*s)/c], 
        a*Sin[(\[Omega]*s)/c], (b*s)/c}];
    basis = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[\[Beta][s], s]] // Simplify;
    {tangent, normal, binormal} = 
      Map[Arrow[{\[Beta][s], \[Beta][s] + #}] &, basis];
    pp = ParametricPlot3D[\[Beta][s], {s, 0, 10}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
    fs = Graphics3D[{Thick, Blue, tangent, Red, normal, Purple, binormal}];

    Manipulate[Show[pp, fs,
       AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
       AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
       Boxed -> False,
       PlotRange -> All
       ] // Evaluate, {{s, 2}, 0, 10},
     ContinuousAction -> True
     ]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
helix = {a*Cos[(\[Omega]*s)/c], a*Sin[(\[Omega]*s)/c], (b*s)/c};
basis = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[helix, s]] // Simplify;
{tangent, normal, binormal} = Map[Arrow[{helix, helix + #}] &, basis];

Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[
   helix /. {a -> a1, b -> b1, c -> c1, \[Omega] -> \[Omega]1, 
     s -> s1}, {s1, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Blue, 
    Dynamic[tangent /. {a -> a1, b -> b1, 
       c -> c1, \[Omega] -> \[Omega]1, s -> s1}], Red, 
    Dynamic[normal /. {a -> a1, b -> b1, 
       c -> c1, \[Omega] -> \[Omega]1, s -> s1}], Purple, 
    Dynamic[binormal /. {a -> a1, b -> b1, 
       c -> c1, \[Omega] -> \[Omega]1, s -> s1}]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, Boxed -> False, 
  PlotRange -> All], {{s1, 5}, 0, 10}, {{a1, 1}, 0, 10}, {{b1, 1}, 0, 
  10}, {{c1, 1}, 0, 10}, {{\[Omega]1, 5}, 0, 10}, 
 ContinuousAction -> True, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 Initialization :> ({a1 = 2, b1 = 1, c1 = 1, \[Omega]1 = 5})]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! May I ask you for a pointer in the Mathematica documentation where I possibly could have found this solution myself? I spent hours searching but didn't find it.

Comment: @Nikolaus I'm sorry, I did not read the documents and textbooks. It's just the experience of using 10 versions of Mathematica.

Comment: No problem, thank you so much again!

Comment: You're welcome!